Spyder not showing autocompletion for imported libraries
I'm experiencing an issue with Spyder where it's not providing autocompletion or suggestions for functions and methods from imported libraries like numpy and pandas. The autocompletion works fine for built-in Python functions (e.g., print()), but when I try to use functions from imported libraries, I get no suggestions.
The imported libraries are added to advanced section in Introspection setting under Completion and linting

everything is updated (Spyder, external libraries)
Spyder's settings looks to be correct

